# original JNI_CreateJavaVM won't continue after DobbyHook

Tags: java-native-interface, reverse-engineering

I'm trying hook `JNI_CreateJavaVM` with `Dobby` for APP testing.

```cpp
jint (*originJNI_CreateJavaVM)(JavaVM **p_vm, JNIEnv **p_env, void *vm_args);
jint JNICALL myJNI_CreateJavaVM(JavaVM **p_vm, JNIEnv **p_env, void *vm_args)
{
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "ddinmys", "%s", "JNI_CreateJavaVM enter");
  jint j = originJNI_CreateJavaVM(p_vm, p_env, vm_args);
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "ddinmys", "%s %d", "JNI_CreateJavaVM leave", j);
  return j;
}

void __attribute__((constructor)) myConstructor(void)
{
  void *p = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");
  if (p != NULL) {
    DobbyHook(p, (void*)myJNI_CreateJavaVM, (void **)&originJNI_CreateJavaVM);
  }
}
```

After run it the system keeping bootloop and `logcat` print as below.

```sh
I/ddinmys (13184): JNI_CreateJavaVM enter
F/libc    (13184): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 13184 (zygote)
I/DEBUG   ( 1448): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   ( 1448): Build fingerprint: 'Android/aosp_shamu/shamu:5.1.1/LYZ28N/0.0.1:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   ( 1448): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   ( 1448): ABI: 'x86'
I/DEBUG   ( 1448): pid: 13184, tid: 13184, name: zygote  >>> zygote <<<
I/DEBUG   ( 1448): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
I/DEBUG   ( 1448):     eax 00000000  ebx b449b6c8  ecx b77b929c  edx b4499000
I/DEBUG   ( 1448):     esi b76ec248  edi bfe6441c
I/DEBUG   ( 1448):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
I/DEBUG   ( 1448):     eip b68598d6  ebp bfe633f8  esp bfe63380  flags 00010292
I/DEBUG   ( 1448):
I/DEBUG   ( 1448): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   ( 1448):     #00 pc 000008d6  /system/lib/libnativehelper.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1448):     #01 pc 0007f3ba  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1448):     #02 pc 00000dc7  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1448):     #03 pc 0000211f  /system/bin/app_process32
I/DEBUG   ( 1448):     #04 pc fffffe4a  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   ( 1448):
I/DEBUG   ( 1448): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_07
```

[image]

I see already hooked `JNI_CreateJavaVM` but won't continue the origin func with fatal.

`F/libc    (13184): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 13184 (zygote)`

Comment: hi, not sure if this might be of interest https://github.com/jmpews/Dobby/issues/160

Comment: hi bro, thanks for your reply. I tried the resolve solution and it does't work. Guess i'm run it on x86 not arm64 talked in the issue.

Comment: I switched to AndHook and works well with x86.